# JavaScript Append New Array at The Beginning HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object like below:

```
var data = [
  {item_name: 'Book', stock: 15},
  {item_name: 'Pencil', stock: 15},
  {item_name: 'Paper', stock: 3}
];
```

And then i generate a list with HTML from the object:

```
console.log(data);
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<li class="list-group-item" id="listGroup">'+data[i].item_name+'<span class="badge">'+data[i].stock+'</span></li>';
}
$('#listItem').html(html);
```

If i add new object, how do i put the new object at the beginning of the list ?

Comment: You are looking for `data.unshift({item_name: 'Foo', stock: 1337})`

Comment: `data.unshift(newData)` and using jQuery `$('#listItem').prepend('<li>...');`

Comment: `data` is an array not an object

Answer (score 1):

try like this.The  `unshift()` method adds new items to the beginning of an array.use `forEach()` for looping with array.

```js
var data = [
  {item_name: 'Book', stock: 15},
  {item_name: 'Pencil', stock: 15},
  {item_name: 'Paper', stock: 3}
];
data.unshift( {item_name: 'new', stock: 10});
//console.log(data);
var html='';
data.forEach(function(element,index,array){
    html += '<li class="list-group-item" id="listGroup">'+data[index].item_name+'<span class="badge">'+data[index].stock+'</span></li>';
$('#listItem').html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listItem">

</div>
```

JS FIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/b1sf7a1d/

Comment: You might forgot one of the requirements of the question _If i add new object, how do i put the new object at the beginning of the list ?_

Comment: @GilleQ. That's what unshift does.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood, but I thought he wanted to append the newElement to his html list too

Comment: @@GilleQ. The  unshift() method adds new items to the beginning of an array.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i want to append the new Element automatically if new array is inserted, and not add it directly

Comment: @metaphor see answer ..this is what you want.

Comment: @ tymeJV see answer.The unshift() method adds new items to the beginning of an array.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati is it possible to `unshift` the array by updating `data`, without using `data.unshift( {item_name: 'new', stock: 10});`. So the `unshift()` method is called inside loop and unshift the new data in list.